# Extracting data using python from the steam api formatted in JSON

Tags: python, json

I want to get the name and percent data from the json string...

```
{'achievementpercentages': {'achievements': [{'name': 'camp_bonus_01_stalingrad_rail_german_engineering', 'percent': 42}, {'name': 'count_camp_1', 'percent': 41.5}
```

Ive been trying to do this using something like...

```
for achievementpercentages in repos:
        print(achievementpercentages['name'])
        print(achievementpercentages['percent'])
```

but this returns the error...
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Shouldn't this be `achievementpercentages['achievements'][0]['name']..` where `0` is the list index for `achievements` values ? There is almost certainly something wrong with the JSON string you provided. You can test it using a JSON validation software available online and correct it.

Comment: That is not JSON. Looks like a Python dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a valid json string but that doesn't mean you can't use it. The issue you're having is explained by the error. Your loop isn't saying what you want to do based on the structure of your dictionary. If your repo variable is filled with a list of many rows(dicts) that look like your example line then your code needs to be:

```
for row in repo:
    for achievement in row['achievementpercentages']['achievements']:
        print achievement['name']
        print achievement['percent']
```

It's a little unclear what repos is... if repos is your entire string you pasted it needs to be:

```
for achievemnt in repo['achievementpercentages']['achievements']:
    print achievement['name']
    print achievement['percent']`
```

Comment: Thanks i realize that i may be doing something incorrectly. However that last piece of code has worked for me, the JSON string is what is returned from the steam API. there may be some formatting that I'm unaware of and so cannot use. Repos was the string apologies fro being unclear.